# Python like Ruby inheritance

Tags: python, ruby

In python, I can do something like this:

```
# say.py
class Speaker:
    def speak(self,word):
        pass
    def Do(self):
        self.speak("hello")
Speaker().Do()
```

If I run this, it would do nothing at all. I can do this in another module:

```
import say
class Test(say.Speaker):
    def speak(self,word):
        print(word)
Test().Do()
```

If I run this, the original `speak` function in `say.py` is overwritten completely since I inherited it when I did:

```
class Test(say.Speaker)
```

So when I run the script, it will print the word rather than doing nothing. I want the name of the script to dynamically change file names without having to edit `say.rb`.

If I ran `say.py` and did:

```
Speaker().do()
```

nothing happens, but when I run the other py module, and have it do:

```
Test.Do()
```

it is overwritten since I inherited it, and changed the function of `speak`. Doing `Speaker().Do()` as it is does nothing, but if I do `Test.Do()`, it does work because of the override.

Is their a ruby equivalent for what I did in python, and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very similar.  Here's 'say.rb':

```
module Say
  class Speaker 
    def speak(word) end
    def Do() speak("Hello") end
  end
end
```

In your other module:

```
require 'say'
class Test < Say::Speaker
  def speak(word)
    puts(word)
  end  
end
```

To demonstrate:

```
Test.new.Do
```

Comment: Thank you, that was stumped me for quite along time you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is.  What have you tried that didn't work?  Read up on [inheritance in Ruby](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html).

You'd literally need only change a few characters in that Python to get it to work in Ruby.